# Calendar plugin to sync with Facebook Page events

Tags: google-calendar, facebook-pages, facebook-events

I'm developing a website for an organisation that, until now, has used Facebook as its only online presence. The organisation wants all information currently available on their Facebook page (please note it is a Facebook 'page' for an organisation and not a Facebook account that an individual uses) to be available on the site.

The problem I'm having is that I am unable to find a Calendar plugin that stays in sync with the organisation's Facebook page events.

I've looked at Google Calendar and I've discovered that it only supports syncing with Facebook 'account' events and not Facebook 'page' events (it does support single events but does not check for new events).

Does anyone know how to get Google Calendar to sync with Facebook 'page' events or failing that, a good 'month-view' web page calendar plugin that obtains its events from a Facebook page?

Answer (score 0):

You can also make and publish one yourself.
The [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) is quite easy to use and I guess the [Facebook Events API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/) can't be that hard either.

Consider using [Google AppEngine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/) with a [CRON job](https://developers.google.com/search/results?q=cron&p=/appengine) to do this, it's quite straightforward and the Google API's work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook aren't too friendly about getting data *out* of their systems, but you can use something like [iCalendar to Event](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Calendar-to-Event/158110800961417) to go the other way - create Facebook events from a Google calendar. It's quite happy to put things on a page rather than personal account.